# FirebaseAnalytics for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-analytics

I used below firebase code:

```
        int month = (int)[components month]; //gives you month
        int day = (int)[components day]; //gives you day
        int year = (int)[components year];

        NSString * obj = @"Date : ";
        NSString * key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d/%d",day,month,year];
       [dictionary setObject:obj forKey:key];


       [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"Game Launch :" parameters:dictionary];
       [FIRAnalytics setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled:true];
```

In firebase dashboard, no where I see message **Game Launch** where this log comes?

Answer (score 2):

**To see events real time in the Firebase StreamView or DebugView**

1. Enable debug logging for iOS (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events#view_events_in_the_xcode_debug_console) to see when events are uploaded in debug console.
2. Go to Firebase console https://console.firebase.google.com
3. Select your app
4. In Analytics Tab Select StreamView or DebugView to see your events real time.

**To see events in the Firebase Dashboard**

In Firebase Dashboard won't show events in real-time.

> You can view aggregrated statistics about your events in the Firebase console dashboards. **These dashboards update periodically throughout the day**. For immediate testing, use the logcat output as described in the previous section.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/events#view_events_in_the_dashboard

Comment: so above code logs in Xcode only? FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"Game Launch :", in this Game Launch: comes only in Xcode? no where it shows in firebasedashboard ?